# Poor Titanfall GPU performance

Tags: pc, performance, titanfall

I have Intel i5 2500k, Nvidia GeForce GTX 560, 16 GB of DDR3 RAM.

Still, Titanfall has really poor performance. I play on lowest possible settings and in HD (1280x720, I think). Still, on large maps, the game drops to ca. 5FPS, making it almost unplayable.

Interesting thing is, that while playing tutorial, I had everything maxed out and it worked like a charm (60 FPS permanently).

Another thing is, that sometimes, it runs relatively fine (~25FPS), while an hour later on the same map, the game is unplayable.

Any ideas what to do about this strange behavior? Is it Nvidia driver problem?

---

Update: I'm able to run Crysis 3 on ultra settings without problem.

Comment: How's your internet?  If the tutorial worked fine, then that tells me something is going on in your network or something.

Comment: Nope, 20Mbit/s download, 10Mbit/s upload, ping ~40ms

Comment: Is your cpu socket VRM by any chance overheating? If you have a cheap motherboard and have overclocked the CPU, it could be especially true, because the CPU cooler hardly/doesn't cool the VRM and it can lead to frequency drops. Since it only affects multiplayer, it's even more reasonable that this is the case, because multiplayer puts extra stress on the CPU, because of all the players.

Comment: I have very strong cooler on my cpu (never seen temperature go over 50°C). I have ASUS P8P67-M PRO (rev 3.0) motherboard, so we're really not talking about cheap mb here.

Comment: Try a different server.

Comment: @user2486570 When you say ping ~40ms, is that for the specific server you are trying to play on ? In any case, ase Brok3n said, try a different server. Just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

They recently added an ambient occlusion setting in an update, which may have been set to on by default. This severely lowers FPS. I would double check that setting to make sure it is off.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the drivers. Before it installs it asks to do a clean install, try that. If that does not work try decreasing the texture details.

Answer (score -3):

Does your case have good cooling? If your GPU is hot it wont preform at its best. Also if you are running any programs in the background close them as they are slowing the game down. If your still having FPS issues i recomend you use Razer Game Booster. Razer Game booster will run any game faster and you will get more performance. [Download Razer Game Booster](http://www.razerzone.com/cortex/game-booster)

Comment: Well, I have enough cooling and with 16GB of RAM, I don't think the problem is in some background process.